# Struts 2 jquery autocompleter with forceValidOption="false"

Tags: jquery, struts2, autocomplete, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-plugin

I have set the Struts 2 jquery auto complete tag `forceValidOption` to false as:

```jsp
<sj:autocompleter list="destinationAccounts" id="sample" 
            listKey="accountNo" name="toAccount"
            listValue="%{accountNo + \" \" + firstName + \" \" + lastName }"
            forceValidOption="false"/>
```

The `forceValidOption` is not working and it forces the user to select from options and will auto-clean user entered data, when user leaves input.
The generated javascript is as:

```js
var options_sample_widget = {};
options_sample_widget.hiddenid = "sample";
options_sample_widget.selectBox = true;
options_sample_widget.forceValidOption = false;

options_sample_widget.jqueryaction = "autocompleter";
options_sample_widget.id = "sample_widget";
options_sample_widget.name = "toAccount.accountNo_widget";
options_sample_widget.href = "#";
options_sample_widget.formids = "ownToOtherForm";


jQuery.struts2_jquery_ui.bind(jQuery('#sample_widget'),options_sample_widget);
```

It shows that the `forceValidOption` is set.

Should I set other options to make it work?!

I have test it in the showcase and still I could not make it work.

If there is a bug here, can I use jQuery autocomplete function directly and disable this feature ?!

Comment: https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/issues/18.

Comment: @AleksandrM he opened that bug report :D

Comment: @AndreaLigios: I've figured that out. :) Still worth mentioning it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`<sj:autocompleter>`](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/AutocompleterTag) without `href` attribute is used to load a static list.

If it's used with `selectBox="true"`, it renders `select` tag to hold its options and two input fields: one is a hidden field which value is submitted, and another is a combobox. The value from this field should be set to a hidden field.
To make it work you should set the following function

```js
$(".s2j-combobox-input.ui-autocomplete-input").keyup(function(e){
  $("#sample").val($(".s2j-combobox-input.ui-autocomplete-input").val())
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Roman ! So it seems that this feature is not working and we should use this workaround until bug fix.

Comment: Your code will only set the hidden value which is associated to this input. If you want that the input shows the user value `$(".s2j-combobox-input.ui-autocomplete-input").blur(function(e){
 $(".s2j-combobox-input.ui-autocomplete-input".val( $("#sample").val() )
});`